# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject not setting json values to properties

Tags: json, parsing, deserialization

i am deserializing my json string to a class properties

my json

```
[
  {
    "Events": [
      {
        "DeviceId": "apc51"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

my deserializing code

```
TcpClient client = (TcpClient)obj;
var stream = client.GetStream();
string imei = String.Empty;
string recivedData = "";
Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
int i;
try
{
    while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
    {
        string hex = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
        recivedData = recivedData + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
    }

    //recivedData="[\r\n  {\r\n    \"Events\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"DeviceId\":\"apc51\"\r\n      }\r\n    //]\r\n  }\r\n]"

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Events>>(recivedData);
```

result value I am getting is

```
Count = 1   System.Collections.Generic.List<TCPSW.Events>
[0] {TCPSW.Events}  TCPSW.Events
DeviceId    null    string
```

I am getting DeviceId value is null

modal class is

```
 public class Events
    {
        [JsonProperty("DeviceId")]
        public String DeviceId { get; set; }

    }
```

what am I missing? is it any issue in json?